# Tokenize my CSV in one list rather than separate using Python

Tags: python, tokenize

I want to tokenize my CSV in one list rather than a separate list?

```
with open ('train.csv') as file_object:
    for trainline in file_object:
        tokens_train = sent_tokenize(trainline)
        print(tokens_train)
```

This is how I am getting the output:

```
['2.1 Separated of trains']
['Principle: The method to make the signal is different.']
['2.2 Context']
```

I want all of them in one list

```
['2.1 Separated of trains','Principle: The method to make the signal is different.','2.2 Context']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `sent_tokenize()` returns a list, you could simply extend a starting list each time.

```
alltokens = []

with open ('train.csv') as file_object:
    for trainline in file_object:
        tokens_train = sent_tokenize(trainline)
        alltokens.extend(tokens_train)
    print(alltokens)
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
with open ('train.csv') as file_object:
    alltokens = [token for trainline in file_object for token in sent_tokenize(trainline)]
print(alltokens)
```

Both solutions will work even if `sent_tokenize()` returns a list longer than 1.

Comment: [['2.1 Separated of trains'], ['Principle: The method to make the signal is different.'],['2.2 Context']]

Comment: This is what I get from your method.

Comment: How can we merge them all in one list?

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was useful, please consider to accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an empty list

```
out = []
```

And inside the loop append items to it.

```
out.append(tokens_train)
```

Maybe you have to modify your tokenizer too.